# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой :TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

Исходный код

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 3, 'c': 4}
d = list(x.keys())
for key in sorted(d):
    print(key + '=>' + d[key])
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python projects/qq.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(key + '=>' + d[key])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Читал Mark Lutz - Python, 5th Edition и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Использую python 3.6.

Comment: пожалуйста, нажмите кнопку [edit], вставьте туда текст ошибки и ваш код, выделите его и нажмите `{}` среди кнопок редактора или Ctrl-K на клавиатуре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что там должно быть `x[key]`, а не `d[key]`, иначе код не имеет особого смысла.

Answer (score 1):

В переменной `d` у вас список. Доступ к элементам списка осуществляется по числовому индексу. Например `d[0]`. Но в переменной цикла `key` у вас не числа, а буквы - a, b, c и d.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что там должно быть x[key], а не d[key]...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ответы - в ответы.